# Capacitor v3 Motion api - using AccelListenerEvent properties

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin, ionic6

I am using Capacitor version 3 and I'm trying out the Motion Api.

In the documentation [here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/motion), the AccelListenerEvent comes with some properties which I want to set but there are no examples of how to use this.

So the part I'm using is addListener(‘orientation’, …)

I basically want to set the interval.

I've added this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PluginListenerHandle } from '@capacitor/core';
import { Motion, AccelListenerEvent } from '@capacitor/motion';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  accelHandler: PluginListenerHandle;
  accelListenerEvent: AccelListenerEvent;

  constructor() {
    this.accelListenerEvent.interval = 10;
  }
```

But it doesn't like it in the constructor.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to set these properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the properties this way:

```
Motion.addListener('accel', event => {
  console.log('Interval:', event.interval);
});
```

Since this is an event, you can only receive values, not set them.

Comment: How do I set the interval then? If you go to the link I provided and scroll down to: addListener(‘orientation’, …) ... you will see that under Interfaces there's "AccelListenerEvent" which have some properties. One is interval. How do I set that? It just doesn't say how to in the documentation :(

Comment: You cannot set this property. It's read-only. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceMotionEvent.

Comment: Wow...that's bad news :( But at least I know now. :)